How to trigger a circuit when getting close to it physically?
Context : A relative of mine is working on a game. They would like to be able to have an event to start when getting close to say 50cm to an object (any direction).
What would be a way to implement this ?
We've been thinking about wearing a wristband or ring that acts as marker for the main circuit but other than that we have absolutely no clue how this could be done.
Thanks in advance for your help !
Vincent

There are radar or lidar or ultrasonic ranging devices available at low-cost which you can use to build such a circuit. Or you could build one of those from scratch which I wouldn't recommend :-) .

The following do the core work for you. You still need to design the overall system -but these give the basic udea. Example only here NOT a recommendation. || Ones like this are very common. A web search on rangefinder or ultrasonic rangefinder for DIY ultrasonic rangefinder for somewhere would find much. So also radar rangefinder or even maybe lidar rangefinder.

Does the "object" need to identify which "marker" has got close to it (to take marker specific action), or just that any marker has got close to it?

Does the detection need to be omnidirectional - ie independent of the direction of approach? Ultrasonics can be quite directional, but for close range you could use a conical reflector to get omni coverage. Microwave movement sensors might be more omni out of the box.

IR proximity sensor? IR beam cage? PIR sensor? Camera with some Raspberry Pi detecting movement in video frames?

does it make a difference whether someone wearing a marker gets close to it, or just anything or anybody? (the marker thing is an additional complication, tbh.)

is the object stationary? How tall can the object be, i.e., could you have a mast above the object?
